# Is there a printer setting for handbooks?

Tags: windows-7, printing, printer

I have a booklet that is in page order but when printed it is not in page order. I am guessing it is a printer setting that for the life of me can't figure out & this handbook is rather pressing on time.

Comment: You need to provide more information: What application (Word? PowerPoint? LibreOffice? OpenOffice? Adobe?) and what version. What printer (and what driver). And it might be helpful to describe the layout/configuration of the booklet (single 8½×11” pages? pairs of 5½×8½” pages embedded in 8½×11” pages?) etc.

Comment: Typically, booklets involve folded sheets and printing on both sides.  If you fold 8.5x11 in half and make a four page booklet, one side will have pages 4 and 1, the other 2 and 3.  You need to prepare the document with the correct sequence or use software to convert it. Something like this: http://clickbook.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this.

Many printers have a "booklet" setting. With this setting, the printer will print half size (2 A5s on A4). The first and last page will be on sheet 1, side 1; page 2 and last -1 on sheet 1, side 2, etc. Then, when all pages are printed, you can fold the whole stack in the middle to get a booklet in the correct order. The driver will typically add blank pages if your booklet does not have a page count that is a multiple of 4.

Unfortunately, it depends on the printer. Go through your printer settings to see if it has a booklet option. If your printer cannot duplex, it almost certainly will not print booklets either.

Some standard software, such as Acrobat and Word, can achieve this too. In Acrobat, just select Booklet Printing under Page Scaling in the Print dialogue box. Word lets you set up booklets from Page Setup.

Alternatively there is software to achieve the same thing, like http://clickbook.com as fixer1234 mentioned in his comment. Finally, many printing services can print booklets from your file. See for example http://www.whirlwindprint.com/products/view/129/Booklet-Printing-Services .

Comment: I wasn't aware they had added this feature to Word or Acrobat (or printers).  Good to know.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a feature in Word 2007.

Comment: @fixer1234 It's there in Word 2010, under Page Setup > Margin tab. Select "Book fold" under Pages > Multiple Pages

Comment: @fixer1234: It's in the same place in Word 2007. (Not very easy to find if you don't know exactly where to look.)

Comment: @Scott: well darn if you ain't right.  I never would have found it or if I had, I wouldn't have recognized what it was.

Comment: @fixer1234: Don't thank me; thank hdhondt.

Comment: Of course, in the case of Word selecting Book Fold completely repaginates the document. Acrobat (or the printer) simply scales each page to 50% (that's area, linear scaling is 71%) so it can print 2 pages per sheet.